# how to add textbox in the mail body?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net and C#.

I have a requirement in which i need to add one textbox in the mail body.
After the user registration, i need to send a welcome mail. i tried to add the input tag in the mail body, but i am able to see on [ ](two square brackets).

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you need. Do you really need a text input box inside an e-mail? What code do you expect to handle the value of this input box? The idea seems just crazy. Probably what you need is something different, but it is not clear from you question.

Comment: ok.. let me tell u.. I want to add "<input name="text" type="text" style="color:#666666;" value="Enter a name, keyword, or anything" size="50"/>" inside my email.  If the user clicks on the search button besides the textbox it should redirect to some page. I hope my requirement is clear now.

Comment: What you normally would do is send an email that contains a link to a webpage. When the link is clicked, the web-browser opens up and loads the page. The page contains the textbox and submit button, backed by some server-side code to process the results.

Comment: here its not processing, rather its getting the data and passing to a web page when clicked on the button.
i just wanna display a textbox and a button/image...

Comment: Let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: E-mails are just not intended for such usage and thus e-mail clients are not designed to handle this. It seems just weird to expect that user would enter something inside e-mail and click some button. I think the best you can do is a link to a page with your form as it was suggested above.

Comment: Guys, I am able to do this..
I just added text box, like with <input/> tags in a from and had given a submit button. i set the action of the form as the link of the external site. when i click on the submit button in the form, its re-directing to the url. This is working perfectly on gmail. But its  not working on outlook, may be the way outlook renders is different(dnt know).

Comment: It's now 8 years later.  Has anyone gotten this working on a variety of email clients (Outlook/Hotmail, gmail, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this. Like other people said: this is impossible at best.

Think of the vast variety of email clients nowadays and the Spam community actively trying to break hell loose on your computer each day. Basic HTML is allowed in email, images (if not embedded) are blocked, Javascript is not allowed.

For your own sake, try to redefine this requirement to be input on a webpage with a link in the welcome email. If you continue to find a solution to this, you'll end up pulling your hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is impossible.

AFAIK, HTML email is rendered at the client using a parser, not a fully functional web client.
 So I don't know email clients which will allow you to do this.

More information about HTML e-mails could be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_e-mail).

Comment: @Carles: my answer is only an assumption. I've heart that Outlook uses Word to display it.